# What do the operators "<>" mean in Python?

Tags: python, operators, tetris

I'm trying to understand another author's code for writing a Parser in the "NAND to Tetris" project but don't understand what they mean when using the "<>" operators as shown in this chunk of code. I have included their constructor for reference to the self.commands function.

```
def __init__(self,fname):
    self.fname = fname
    self.commands = open(fname, 'r').readlines()
    self.cleanUp()
.
.
.

 def hasMoreCommands(self):
    """Return True if more commands to parse else return False"""
    return self.commands <> [ ]
```

Seems to me like its an easier way of determining if there are more lines in the code. Is that correct? Thank you for any input regarding this question! Please let me know if more info would help.

Comment: Not equal, same as `!=`.

Comment: I think it started as "less than or greater than", similar to how `<=` means "less than or equal". But that makes it synonymous with "not equal".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.X, `<>` is same as `!=` but the usage is obsolete and is discouraged in favour of the newer usage which is `!=`

Refer the manual for the [Comparision](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) section

So, `return self.commands <> [ ]` is same as `return self.commands != [ ]` which means the self.commands is not an empty list which as per your docstring

> Return True if more commands to parse else return False

Comment: The whole code block is not idiomatic Python - if you want to test if a list is empty or not, just test it as a Boolean. `if self.commands:`. Empty lists are `False`, non-empty lists are `True`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: That is a separate argument which I didn;t want to digress.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link and explanation! Abhijit: I will mark your comment as the answer when it allows me to!

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper in this context I think the original form is actually *easier* to understand than `return bool(self.commands)`.

Comment: Well, we don't see the calling context - I personally wouldn't have a method for that test at all. But, yeah, this is probably not a useful digression.

Comment: "Discouraged"? Python has been throwing syntax error for 8 years...